# Redirect URL in Android Native App

Tags: android, azure, android-fragments, adal

I am trying to implement SSO using [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android) Azure adal library in a native android application.

I could not see any documentation on Redirect URL in android, Once I enter valid user name and password in microsoft portal, I could not redirect to my LoginFragment using Redirect URL.

My AuthenticationContext object looks like this.

```
AuthenticationContext mAuthContext;
mAuthContext.acquireToken(
       wrapFragment(LoginFragment.this),
       Constants.AdlaConfig.RESOURCE_ID,
       Constants.AdlaConfig.CLIENT_ID,
       "https://LoginFragment", // Redirect URL
       "", 
       PromptBehavior.Auto, 
       "nux=1",
       getCallback());
```

On debugging i could see that this is an Redirect issue, any help guys!

Comment: Just figured out that the Reply URL does not matters as long its a valid URI and the App registered in AZURE AD is of type Native.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you had resolved your issue. As references, the document list below may be useful for understanding about authentication & SSO on Android.

1. How to [configure a native client application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication#optional-configure-a-native-client-application)
2. [Add authentication to your Android app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-users), and the [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-users#a-nameredirecturlaadd-your-app-to-the-allowed-external-redirect-urls) about redirect url on Android App
3. [How to enable cross-app SSO on Android using ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-sso-android)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Peter! for the links. Yes, i have resolved my issue.